# How to receive json param in spring boot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have a Json like the following.

```
{"person":[{"name":"asd","age":"22"},{"name":"asd","age":"22"}]}
```

but it could also be:

```
{"person":[{"name":"asd","age":"22"},{"name":"asd","age":"22"}],"city":["NewYork"],"student":"false"}
```

How can I receive it in a Spring Boot Controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `@RequestBody` annotation.

```
@RequestMapping("/api/example")
public String example(@RequestBody String string) {
    return string;
}
```

Later, add some validations and business logic.

You can generate custom class with http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/. Once generated you can expect your custom class instead of `String`.

For further instructions, I find [this tutorial](https://kielczewski.eu/2014/04/developing-restful-web-service-with-spring-boot/) interesting.

Comment: After I asked, I found out that it was a stupid question.Thank you for still answering this question.And thank for every click 'down vote' guys,it makes me realize that this is a bad question.

Comment: English is no my mother language.My ability to express is limited.

Comment: @NBsaw- the question just don't show the effort you did. Before asking here, I suggest reading [ask] and [mcve] - they help to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive the json like below, Spring Boot will convert your json into model(For example "Comment" model below) which you defined.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResultModel createComment(@RequestBody Comment comment) {...}
```

Answer (score -2):

1) You need to difine your rest controllers. Example

```
@Autowired
UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUsers() {
    List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
    if (users.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

2) Define your pojo: Example

```
public class User {

 String name;
 String age;

 public User(String name, String age) {
     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;
 }

 public String getName() {
     return name;
 }

 public String getAge() {
     return age;
 }
}
```

3) Define a service

@Service
    public class UserService {

```
  public List<User> findAllUsers(){
    // Those are mock data. I suggest to search for Spring-data for    interaction with DB.
     ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
     User user = new User("name", "5");
     users.add(user);
     return users;
  }
 }
```

You can follow [this](http://websystique.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-rest-api-example/) tutorial. If you want to just send a json message to a spring boot rest controller you can use a rest client like postman.